# Mongoose include model with dependencies

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a node application based off of [This example](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo/blob/master/app/models/article.js).

`server.js` has the following:

```
fs.readdirSync(__dirname + "/app/model").forEach(function (file) {              
    if (~file.indexOf(".js")) {                                                 
        require (__dirname + "/app/model" + "/" + file);                        
    }                                                                           
});
```

This includes all of the files from `app/model`.  This works, but the problem is that *my* models have reference dependencies that don't come up in the example.  Specifically I have a model like this:

```
ResourceSchema = new Schema({
    "comment": [Comment]
});
```

However when I run `node` I get an error that `Comment` is not defined, which is not really unexpected.

This does not come up in the example even though the schema has a reference because it uses:

```
user: {type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'User'},
```

My question is, should I use `"comment": {type: [Schema.ObjectId], ref: "Comment"}` instead (or something else?)  Is there a proper way to include the schema reference for Comment in the Resource Schema declaration?

Comment: `"comment": [Comment]` is not a references array, but a subdocuments array. It means that all the comments will be stored directly inside of the current document. If you want to store references you should write `"comment": [{type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Comment'}]` instead.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny I think this would be great as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to define an array of references, you should use the following definition:

```
ResourceSchema = new Schema({
  "comment": [{type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Comment'}]
});
```

The way you defined comments is used to define an array of subdocuments ([see mongoose API docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)).

So, you should use it only if you want to store all your comments directly inside of the parent document. In this case `Comments` schema should be already defined, or required from another module.